# Namespace is not working in contoller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created Mycontoller.php inside app/controllers

```
class MyController extends BaseController {
    public function showWelcome($name){
    return "Hello $name !! ";
    }
}
```

When i use inside routes.php
Route::get('user/{name}','App\Controllers\MyController@showWelcome');

It is giving exception

> ReflectionException Class App\Controllers\MyController does not exist

Comment: Did you updated auto-loading in composer??? Did you correctly add auto-loading in composer.json file...psr-0/psr-4/or direct loading...etc..please check

Comment: thanks it works after comoser dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

just use `MyController@showWelcome`  With the code you showed, you don't have any defined namespaces. You should make it

```
Route::get('user/{name}','App\Controllers\MyController@showWelcome');
```